# как определять с какой скоростью user прокручивает страницу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {

});
```

нужно вывести в консоль с какой скоростью прокручивается страница при ее прокручивание ?

Comment: а в чем скорость? км/ч, м/с, px/ms?) нужно вынести переменную времени и смотреть какой отрезок за какое время прокрутился

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let checkScrollSpeed = (settings => {
    settings = settings || {};
  
    let lastPos, newPos, timer, delta, 
        delay = settings.delay || 50; 
  
    clear = () => lastPos = null;delta = 0;
    clear();
    
    return function(){
      newPos = window.scrollY;
      if ( lastPos != null ){ 
        delta = newPos -  lastPos;
      }
      lastPos = newPos;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(clear, delay);
      return delta;
    };
})();


window.onscroll = _ => console.log( checkScrollSpeed());
```

```css
body {
  height:5000px;
}
```